# Time dependent coordinate transformations and an object that is purely temporal

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, newtonian-gravity

If I have determined that part of my Levi-Civita connection is purely time-dependent,

$$\Gamma^i{}_{j0}= \Gamma^i{}_{j0}(t)$$

can that object be set to zero via a time-dependent coordinate transformation (spatial rotation)

$$x^{'i} = R^i{}_j(t)x^j?$$

I am working on a derivation in Newton-Cartan gravity.